# Powershell selectnodes not returning content

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun>
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult>
      <Output>
        <StdOut>content</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
</TestRun>
```

I can load this file with this:

```
$doc = [xml](Get-Content "file.xml")
```

I want to find the list of `StdOut` elements and display them using PowerShell. I've tried this code (and many variations) with no success:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//Output")
```

Why does this not return anything?

If I print the value `$xml` I see this:

```
xml                            TestRun
---                            -------
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" TestRun
```

So I know the file is loaded - I just can't seem to find any information from within it.

Comment: There's `$doc` for loaded XML data, but then you query different uninitialised variable `$xml`. Is that a copy-paste error? Try `$xml.Save([console]::out)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Can you post the *exact* code you’re using to reproduce the issue? If your code is something like ```$xml = …; $xml; $xml.SelectNodes("//Output")``` you might be falling foul of a *display* issue where ```format-table``` decides column names for the first row of output within 300ms (```$xml```)  which means it shows a *blank* row for the second output due to there being no common columns between the two outputs. If that’s the case, your code is *working*, just not *displaying* the output. You can test this with ```$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//Output"); write-host $nodes.Length```

Comment: Another test is ```$xml.SelectNodes("//Output”) | ft``` which will force the output from this line to be shown in a separate table with its own column names - again, this is a *display* issue. Don’t use ```| ft``` in your code to do data processing - it’s only meant for display / logging purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, but I will be closing this post. The XML I posted was a much shortened version of the `dotnet test` Logger output, for brevity and proprietary data. Unfortunately, I found that the Logger was adding an `xmlns` attribute with an invalid URL value and this caused the PowerShell XML document loading to fail. I have solved this by loading the file as text, replacing that attribute with `””` then converting the text into XML in memory.